# Where does the term "lumped" come from anyway?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I think I understand the idea of dealing with lumped circuit elements in electrical engineering, but how did they come up with the name "lumped"?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams He'd be savaged with that dictionary lookup question on esc, maybe http://ell.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Some times this forum displays the to UK or US origination  ignoring the internationalism

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the dictionary explains it: -

[image]

This makes sense to me as applying to lumping circuit elements.

Comment: So basically it's called lumped because we treat all the elements as having the properties of ideal elements without discerning between the individual elements themselves?  I guess that makes sense, it just seems like a strange use of the word. I guess something like "ideal circuit elements" would make more sense to me at least.  Any idea where the use of lumped in this case came from?

Comment: @nonex Ah that's a different question. Think of a cable, a transmission line - it has no individual components yet we can, for the sake of analysing the cable create lumped elements of R, L, C and G and then we can make sense of it by using simple maths. For instance, this is how we calculate the characteristic impedance of the cable - we use a lumped model for a small fractional length of cable then, we extend it's characteristics to theorize on the whole cable.

Answer (score 3):

Lumped as in grouped together, discrete elements as opposed to distributed or continuous. Compare a discrete "lumped" capacitor and the capacitance per meter of a coaxial cable. The main difference is the use of the wave equation for the distributed case.

Comment: But couldn't such a cable be modeled as a capacitor in a circuit?

Comment: @sherrellbc yes, depending upon how it is used.  If you are looking at signal propogation _along_ the length then NO.